# How to create a skin for Filezilla?

Tags: themes, filezilla, skin

I would like to contribute a Theme / Skin for Filezilla, the opensource FTP client.

Are there any tutorials on how to create one? Cannot seem to find one.

(First posted on SuperUser, declared off-topic. Not sure where this question fits best. Please advise before downvoting, thank you.)

Comment: I'd say, it's definitely off-topic here. Your Super User question was closed because you asked for a tutorial (what if off-topic, thought I would vote your question down for that personally). Ask "how to do it" instead.

Comment: Good tip, thank you. Will delete this question and retry SU